# How to calculate area or centroid of the_geom in CartoDB?

Tags: postgis, carto

Is it possible to calculate area or centroid of the_geom in cartoDB?

It would not be a huge time saver, and I am doubtful that it is an option but figured I would ask.

Comment: It's definitely possible with SQL. Do you want to calculate it for a single row, or to create a new column with that information for each geometry in your table?

Comment: Are you open to a PostGIS solution?

Comment: sorry I am just now getting back to this. I'm open to PostGIS purely because I need to learn as much as I can about it. if you have a solution using PostGIS I'd love to have it on file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using spatial SQL:

```
SELECT *, ST_Area(the_geom) FROM Table
```

[more info](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Area.html)

```
SELECT *, ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(the_geom)) FROM Table
```

[more info](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Centroid.html)

Answer (score 1):

warrieka's answer is correct but there are other ways to do them that might be useful.

#### Area

Area calculations are going to be in whatever the projection of the geometry is though. So for area, distance, length type functions it can be a lot more useful to cast them as `geography` so your results are in meters (or square meters).

```
SELECT ST_Area(the_geom::geography) area_sqm FROM tablename
```

#### Center

Centroid of geometries are just as you expect. However, if you have interested shapes in your geoms, sometimes they can fall outside of your actual polygons! If you just want a point that is inside your geometry and similar to center, you can use PointOnSurface

```
SELECT ST_PointOnSurface(the_geom) the_geom FROM tablename
```

Comment: Andrew, is there a way to show lon and lat coordinates instead of the point for the centroid?

Comment: also, is there a way to cast Area in feet rather than meters? a substitute command for "geography"? Thanks again!